# Scraper through all the records until reach file and input into sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Not sure how to proceed.  Not sure how to load the data into a sqlite table.

https://pastebin.com/wxmaNACf

```
#create sqllite engine
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

#load results to soup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

#iterate through.  How do I load the data parsed into the data table.
for td_tag in soup.find_all('td'):
    print(td_tag.text, td_tag.next_sibling)
    context = (td_tag.text)
```

Need to have a sqlite table with 5 columns.  The first column is a company name, the second column has date(s) by region without a delimiter, i.e. North America April 2019  Europe May 2019    Asia October 2019.  The third column are comments.  The fourth column has text that is linked i.e. iPhone 6S .  The last column has comments.

Comment: Data is scraped from a website.  Looks like the following: https://pastebin.com/gQnrdny3

Answer (score 0):

Only being limited to what you have provided, I can only make a general solution.

Given:

```
html = '''
<tr>
       <td style="min-width: 5px; width: 150px; text-align: left;">
          <strong>
          Apple
          </strong>
       </td>
       <td style="min-width: 5px; width: 290px;">
          <div align="center" style="text-align: left;">
             April 1, 2020
          </div>
       </td>
       <td style="min-width: 5px; width: 48px; text-align: center;">
          <div align="center"></div>
       </td>
       <td style="min-width: 5px; width: 133px; text-align: center;">
          <div align="center"></div>
       </td>
       <td style="min-width: 5px; width: 437px;">
          Blah1, blah2
       </td>
    </tr>'''
```

You'd then have something similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

df = pd.DataFrame()
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    td = row.find_all('td')
    data_list = [ data.text.strip() for data in td ]
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data_list])

    df = df.append(temp_df)



df.reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_sql('new_table', con=engine)
```